# Django+html, broken pipe on Safari when play video

Tags: html, django, safari

I just served static video locally, and play it in the video tag.

On chrome, it works fine.

But on Safari, it returns

```
[24/Dec/2015 02:44:21] "GET /static/home/background.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 286720
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
self._write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 328, in write
self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
[24/Dec/2015 02:44:21] "GET /static/home/background.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50378)
```

And my html code is simple as following,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static "home/home.css" %}" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passero+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: homefont;
        src: local(Sohoma_Light_Condensed.ttf) format('truetype');
 }

    div {
    font-family: homefont;
    }
</style>
<title>
Kidy Vision
</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Photography</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Computer Vision</a>

                <ul class= "sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Project</a> </li>
        </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="{% static "home/body.png" %}" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="{% static "home/background.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>

<div class="tagline">
      <nh></nh>  Art&dot;Technology&dot;Life
</div>
```

The video plays in the "full-screen-bg" div class. Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe this is related to the way Safari proxies video playback to quicktime and the limitations of the Django dev server (only one connection).  A possible workaround would be to modify the static view to return a redirect to the local path (`C:`... on windows `/Users/`... on Mac) instead of  the remote path, though I haven't tested this.  Another workaround would be to proxy the serving of video to another, more capable server.